# Why is the paper_trail gem trying to do an empty insert in Rails 4.2/Ruby 2.2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I have an app that was recently upgraded to Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0. Since the upgrade I am seeing the following exception in the production environment:

> Mysql2::Error: Field 'item_type' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `versions` VALUES ()

This doesn't seem to occur consistently. I only know this exists because of ExceptionNotification emails where this occurred with other users. I made several attempts to recreate the issue, but it never happens for me despite executing the same code where this occurred.

Also I want to mention that in all of the models that call has_paper_trail I am passing no options, so there are no limitations on what attributes are tracked. It seems like if a version was being inserted it should always have some kind of change.

This never happened until we upgraded from Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3 to Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0.

I just check GitHub and according to the Gemfile.lock it looks like we went from paper_trail 2.7.2 to 3.0.6.

What is causing this to happen and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/404

Comment: Thanks! It did seem to be an issue with the version being used. Upgrading paper_trail 4.0.0.beta fixed this.